# Finding orthocentre of $\Delta$ formed by intercepts of plane $3x+y+3z=9$

Tags: geometry, triangle-centres

> **Question:**
>   The plane $3x+y+3z=9$ intersects the co-ordinate axes at $A, B, C$. Find orthocentre $(H)$ of $\Delta ABC$.

We see $\Delta ABC$ is isoceles, so let's assume $H = (h, k, h)$, as vertices $A$ and $C$ are symmetrical about $y$-axis.

It follows that, $AH \perp BC$, then 
$$(h-3, k, h)\cdot(0, -9,3)=0$$
$$\Rightarrow h=3k$$

Also, as $H$ lies on plane itself, then
$$3h+k+3h=9$$ $$\Rightarrow 6h=9-k$$

On solving, we get, $$H=(27/19, 9/19,27/19)$$

Is this a proper way of finding orthocentre? (Bcoz, my answer isn't matching with the key)

---

The correct answer is:

> (1,1,3)

Comment: $(1,1,3)$ is not on the plane. Maybe $(1,3,1)$

Comment: Also, looking at my previous comment, $(1,3,1)$ is the incenter, not the orthocenter.

Comment: Your result is absolutely correct and the "key" is wrong (provided that both problem and key are correctly cited).

Comment: @Andrei $(1,3,1)$ is the centroid.

Comment: @user Thanks. Sorry for my mistake

Comment: Ah! Thanks @user